# Docker cannot mount to a directory from nfs share

Tags: docker, nfs, bind-mount

I have an nfs share setup from my NAS with the docker host.

```
10.237.1.128:/mnt/storage/media     15T   47G   15T   1% /storage
```

I am trying to mount a container in /storage/media/library but I get.

```
ERROR: for syncthing  Cannot start service syncthing: error while creating mount source path '/storage/media/library': mkdir /storage/media/: permission denied
```

The container was working fine before when I was mounting to a local directory.

```
---
version: "2.1"
services:
  syncthing:
    image: lscr.io/linuxserver/syncthing:latest
    container_name: syncthing
    hostname: syncthing #optional
    environment:
      - PUID=1000
      - PGID=1000
      - TZ=America/Los_Angeles
    volumes:
      - ./config:/config
      - /storage/media/library:/library
    ports:
      - 8384:8384
      - 22000:22000/tcp
      - 22000:22000/udp
      - 21027:21027/udp
    restart: unless-stopped
```

I made sure the user with ID 1000 owns all the directories and files. It's also the same user with ownership of the share.
Is there something I am missing?

Comment: When you say "I am trying to mount a container in /storage/media/library", I assume you mean the other way around, that you're trying to mount /storage/media/library in the container, is that right? Regarding the docker compose file, is that the file with the local directory, or with the NFS mount? Is this that the yaml file that made docker fail?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to mount that in the container. The /storage/media/library mount is the NFS share the ./config is a local directory. This is the one that fails.

Comment: a wild guess, you (that is docker) are trying root access over NFS. docker start as root as it must bind port.